# Material for mkdocs collapse and expand table of contents

Tags: javascript, html, read-the-docs, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I want this:[readthedocs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqIxx.png)

Instead of this: [material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymlwt.png)

I haven't seen anything that would help with this in the material for mkdocs nav setup

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's a stack of good looking [themes](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/choosing-your-theme/) available for [MkDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/).

Choose between the built in themes: [mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/choosing-your-theme/#mkdocs) and [readthedocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/choosing-your-theme/#readthedocs). Select one of the third-party themes listed on the MkDocs Themes wiki page, **OR** build your own.

Mixing layouts from different themes has a learning curve.

As a first step you'll need to install and try the [**ReadTheDocs-Dropdown**](https://github.com/cjsheets/mkdocs-rtd-dropdown).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of Material for MkDocs is that sections are collapsible. It would require extra effort to change that. Perhaps your `mkdocs.yaml` contains a setting like the [Navigation expansion](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/setup/setting-up-navigation/?h=navigation#navigation-expansion)?